# Why was this question pertaining to clockwork and Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk closed as Not A Real Question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, not-a-real-question

The following question just got closed for lack of realness:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691390/how-to-use-clockwork-with-amazon-aws-elastic-beanstalk

I'm stumped. What makes this question less real than any of the non-closed questions elsewhere on the site?

And for future reference, how I can ask questions that are more "real"?

Comment: +1.  The question looks perfect to me.  Vote to reopen.

Comment: Given that the first commenter on your question is a 1 rep user, it is likely that a mod converted his answer to a comment and then closed your question.

Answer (score 6):

The explanation under the Close Reason says

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, **vague, incomplete, overly broad**, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Your question is very vague and broad. Ask yourself

- What did I try so far?
- Where am I stuck exactly?

You did not show any code in your question. How should anyone go about helping you? Writing a tutorial for you?

*Stack Overflow* is about very specific question, best with code. And when you are stuck at 1 point of your task, ask, but not about *How to do this in general*.

**If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.**

Comment: I understand that it needs to be clear, but I disagree wholeheartedly that it is not already so. For anyone with subject matter expertise, it is obvious that Heroku + clockwork is a no-brainer. So asking "How do I do the same thing, but with AWS", does not require additional detail. The first commenter on the post certainly didn't have any trouble interpreting the "realness" of the question...

Comment: Yet you're still plainly asking us to write you a tutorial/documentation. Are you able to answer the two sub-questions raised in this answer? (What you tried and where you are stuck?). That would make it already more specific and less problematic.

Comment: I asked myself the question, can I imagine an entire book that answers the question, and no, no I cannot.  I can imagine a few sentences and possibly a link to an existing module.

Comment: @Bart "My searches so far haven't turned up any specific results."  answers "what have you tried?" OP is expecting there to be a turnkey solution.  Are you expecting OP to say "I tried building half of this on my own from scratch, *now* it's okay for me to ask SO if it's done already."?  And otherwise you're just describing exactly what SO is for. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691528/how-to-connection-pool-memcached-in-java-spymemcached) is a similar question of mine.

Comment: @djechlin If the OP expects us to point him to a turnkey solution, you're getting closer to a NC question. I know too little about this particular scenario to vote on it either way, all I'm saying is that the more specific you can make it, the less likely it is to be closed.

Comment: @Bart I literally don't see how this question can be more specific.  Evidently from both the OP and user754111 and I agree the first commenter as well, this implies an obvious use case or task.  The OP just didn't put work into defending their question against uninformed moderators as well as people familiar with the technologies at hand.  And it's not NC.  On SO it's okay to ask how to do things.

Answer (score -1):

specificity is crucial to obtaining the information you seek.  You must know precisely what your question pertains to, and what you hope to accomplish as a result (if necessary).  That way, people are more informed and able to assist.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to figure out how to use clockwork with Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  The question seems to pertain precisely to the Ruby gem "clockwork" and the service Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk.